# valueAccessor() returning function signature instead of value during custom binding creation

Tags: knockout.js, custom-binding

I'm brand new to Knockout.js and have been following a tutorial. However, my code is not working as expected, because in my custom binding `createDecimal`, `valueAccessor()` is returning the signature of the function instead of the actual value.

I'm using the latest version of Knockout.js as of today, v3.4.2.

```html
<p>First Name <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
<p>Last Name <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
<p>Change First Name <input data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" type="text" name="firstName"></p>
<p>Change Last Name <input data-bind="value: lastName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" , type="text" name="lastName"></p>
<p>Full Name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>
<p>Add new hobby: <input data-bind="value: hobby, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" type="text" name="hobby"><button data-bind="click: addHobby">Add</button></p>
<p>Hobby to possibly be added: <strong data-bind="text: hobby"></strong></p>
<ul data-bind="foreach: hobbies">
  <div>
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeHobby">Remove Hobby</button>
  </div>
</ul>
<p>Total Number of Properties: <strong data-bind="makeDecimal: numberOfHobbies"></strong></p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  ko.bindingHandlers.makeDecimal = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      var numberOfHobbies = valueAccessor();
      console.log("Number of Hobbies", numberOfHobbies);
      var formattedText = "$" + numberOfHobbies.toFixed();
      element.innerText = formattedText;
    }
  };

  function IndexViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable("George");
    self.lastName = ko.observable("Lopez");
    self.hobby = ko.observable();
    self.hobbies = ko.observableArray(["Acting", "Joking", "Speaking"]);
    self.addHobby = function() {
      self.hobbies.push(self.hobby());
    };
    self.removeHobby = function(hobby) {
      self.hobbies.remove(hobby);
    };

    self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
      return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
    });

    self.numberOfHobbies = ko.computed(function() {
      return self.hobbies().length;
    });

  }

  ko.applyBindings(new IndexViewModel());
</script>
```

Comment: You just need to add `ko.track(this);` at the end of your `IndexViewModel`:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjPavm. And, of course, use the plugin (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-es5/0.4.6/knockout-es5.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not natural, but here you need to use `ko.unwrap()` to get the value of the observable.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.makeDecimal = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var numberOfHobbies = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        console.log("Number of Hobbies", numberOfHobbies);
        var formattedText = "$" + numberOfHobbies.toFixed();
        element.innerText = formattedText;
    }
};
```

It's because of the way Knockout manage observables, by replacing them by functions.

Comment: Thanks Jimbot. That solves the problem! This is super weird because I was following along Steve Sanderson's (the original author's) tutorial and his code did not require the unwrap even though he was getting the value of a computed property..

Comment: See [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNiUcuo3Wio). At 19:13, he creates a custom binding to add currency formatting to a computed property `grandTotal`, and he never unwraps the computed property in his custom binding `currencyText`...

Comment: Yes it strange, not sure why it work for him at the time. Anyway, I find this about the [difference between () and unwrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710425/difference-between-unwrapobservable-and). Also, I read somewhere that observable are functions because javascript lack support of encapsulated properties (getter setter) in most browsers. But I can't remember where...

Comment: In this link (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) they get the last value with `var value = valueAccessor();`.  If the property is not an observable, then you have the correct value.  If it is an observable, then `value` is a function, and get the value with `var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);`.  `ko.unwrap()` can be called also to non observables, then it could be used allways.

Comment: In this video, the author is using his own plugin (http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/05/20/knockout-es5-a-plugin-to-simplify-your-syntax/) to simplfity sintax.  You could also see this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414554/optimizing-knockout-tko-alpha3) that talks a new version of Knockout.